# How to define and use static variables in F# class

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Is there a way to have a mutable static variable in F# class that is identical to a static variable in C# class ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You use `static let` bindings (note: while necessary some times, it's none too functional):

```
type StaticMemberTest () =

    static let mutable test : string = ""

    member this.Test 

        with get() = 
            test <- "asdf"
            test
```

Comment: Does this still work? I am getting the error "'let' and 'do' bindings must come before member and interface definitions in type definitions" using the code above.